# Why isn't there a default implementation of NSCoding?

Tags: ios, nscoding

I understand how to use `NSCoding` to convert my objects to archive objects. That's not my question.

What I'm wondering is why there isn't a default implementation of `NSCoding` that could handle probably 99% of cases.

For instance, every time I write a custom class that I want to archive, I perform the following:

1. Implement `-(void)encodeWithCoder:` and `-(id)initWithCoder:`.
2. Go down my property list, writing a pair of statements (one encode, one decode) for each property.

- If the property is an object, I use the encode/decodeObject method.
- If the property is a value, I use the corresponding encode/decode method.
- I always use the property's name as my key.

I would suspect that almost every implementation of `NSCoding` is exactly like mine, with the only changes being the particular properties that need to be manipulated.

It seems to me that this would be a perfect place for a standard implementation, with the option to override if your particular case if funky.

Do I have a misunderstanding of what's going on? If not, could I add a category on `NSObject` to implement this common method on all objects in my projects?

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that the answer to your question is simply that NSCoding was designed long before Objective-C properties existed. (NSCoding was part of the [OpenStep spec](http://www.levenez.com/NeXTSTEP/OpenStepSpec.pdf) in 1994, whereas properties arrived with [Objective-C 2.0](http://theocacao.com/document.page/510) in 2007.) Additionally, some classes have properties that are not appropriate to be serialized for later.

However, your proposed solution could be a great time-saver! At least one such solution already exists. Check out [AutoCoding](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AutoCoding).

Comment: Regarding "many classes have properties...", I agree. Although I suspect that "many" is practically more like "few". At least, I've rarely excluded any properties from classes I'm archiving when implementing NSCoding.

Comment: Could be! If NSCoding and Objective-C 2.0 had been designed at the same time, perhaps "no-archive" could have been one of the property configuration flags (like nonatomic, assign, etc.)!

Comment: Luckily AutoCoding provides several easy ways to skip archiving a certain property.

Comment: Just looking into it now. Thanks for the link!